# How can I check if QPushButton is clicked

Tags: c++, qt, qpushbutton

I want to use an `if-else` statement to check if `QPushButton` is clicked or not.
How can I do this?.

Comment: http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qabstractbutton.html#down-prop

Comment: There is a signal  `clicked()` that you could use to detect clicks.

Comment: You can use pressed() or clicked() signals with custom slots.

Comment: Are you not forced to use `signals` and `slots` in Qt to do this?

Comment: I don't want to use connect

Answer (score 10):

The question does not make sense. Being clicked is not a *state* that you can check; clicking a button is an *event*. It is important to distinguish between states and events.

You handle a button click event by connecting a slot to the signal `QAbstractButton::clicked()`.

Maybe you mean "How do I check if a button is down?". Being down is a state; you check that state using the method `QAbstractButton::isDown()`.

Answer (score 2):

QAbstractButton, QPushButton's parent class, has a checked property (setChecked/isChecked) if you're trying to determine if the button is depressed with the checkable property set to true.